# os._exit(1) does not kill non-daemonic sibling processes

Tags: python, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am writing a python script which has 2 child processes. The main logic occurs in one process and another process waits for some time and then kills the main process even if the logic is not done.

I read that calling os_exit(1) stops the interpreter, so the entire script is killed automatically. I've used it like shown below:

```
import os

from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array

# Main process
def main_process(shared_variable):
    shared_variable.value = "mainprc"
    time.sleep(20)
    print("Task finished normally.")
    os._exit(1)

# Timer process
def timer_process(shared_variable):
    threshold_time_secs = 5
    time.sleep(threshold_time_secs)
    print("Timeout reached")
    print("Shared variable ",shared_variable.value)
    print("Task is shutdown.")
    os._exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Lock()
    shared_variable = Array('c',"initial",lock=lock)
    process_main = Process(target=main_process, args=(shared_variable))
    process_timer = Process(target=timer_process, args=(shared_variable))

    process_main.start()
    process_timer.start()
    process_timer.join()
```

The timer process calls os._exit but the script still waits for the main process to print `"Task finished normally."` before exiting.

How do I make it such that if timer process exits, the entire program is shutdown (including main process)?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to distiguish between `.kill` and `.terminate` a process.BTW: What you are trying to do, could be done withe `process_main.join(5); if process_main.is_alive(): process_main.terminate()`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you. This is what I ended up using: `join()` with a timeout and then manually terminating the process. But I still am not sure why the `os._exit()` didn't kill the entire parent process, like I read it would.

Comment: According to the docs [Exit the process with status n](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit), `os._exit(...` are only related to the calling `process`. There is a [`sys.exit([arg])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) claiming *Exit from Python* but later on stands *only exit the process when called from the main thread*.